# Different types of seats in a van

Tags: single-word-requests

I am writing a scene where I need to describe in a fluid manner where the characters are seated in a minivan. I know the seat next to the driver is the passenger seat or shotgun. This is a vehicle with third row seating so I am  not sure if the seats right behind the driver are the backseat. If they are, what are the ones behind the backseat called? If not, what are the right terms to describe each point?

Comment: I don't think many people "ride shotgun" these days except as a joke. If you say that here (UK) people will look at you sideways. That expression is from the days of coach & horses, well over a century ago.

Comment: You could relate the passengers from the driver's position. "Danny was on the passenger seat, Pete was right behind the driver, and Dave next to him. Jack and John were on the folding seats right at the back.

Comment: *This is a vehicle with three rows of seats.* From front to back, the seats can be described as "next to/along side the driver"; "in the middle row" and "at the back"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it was already established that there were 3 rows of seats, I would call them

Front seats

Mid seats (mid-passenger-seats)

Rear seats

Answer (score 0):

For me the back seat (or row of seats) is always the one furthest from the driver regardless of how many there are. For instance the 'back seat' of a bus is the long one at the back that isn't broken into by the aisle.

If there are three rows of seats the second row can be called the 'middle row' or 'middle seats'; if there are more than three rows the ones between the front and back rows are usually referred to by ordinal number, for instance in a vehicle with four rows of seats they would be called the 'front seats' (one of them is the driver's); the 'second row'; the 'third row' and the fourth row would be called the 'back row' or 'back seats'.

The only time where this gets difficult is when one or more of the seats folds down, particularly if the second row is fixed and the third one much less accessible. These seats are sometimes called 'dickie seats' or 'the third row' and the second row would be called the 'back seats'

Comment: While *middle row* is OK, *middle seats* is problematic, because that phrase may be understood (and is perhaps more likely to be understood) to refer to the seats that are in the middle of each row (that has more than two seats), rather than the seats that constitute the middle row.